# Random Insertion in Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

How can I implement Binary Tree in C++ by inserting elements randomly from left to right without using template class? This is my insertion function. Can anyone point out what's wrong in this? Please provide your suggestions.

```
Node* insert(int data){
    Node* temp=new Node();
    temp->data=data;

    if(root==NULL){
        temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
    }
    else if(!temp->left){
        temp->left=insert(data);
    }
    else if(!temp->right){
        temp->right=insert(data);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Should the two `else if`'s be `root->left` and `root->right` instead of `temp`? And shouldn't you be passing a pointer to this function too if you want it to be recursive like that?

Comment: `root` does not seem to be propagated through the recursion. Likely you are testing against the same value over and over for similar results. Can't make good suggestions on what you should be doing without a [mcve].

Comment: "by inserting elements randomly from left to right without using template class" i did not understand this.

Comment: You might want to look what *is* a binary tree before constructing one. I don't see any kind of value comparison in your code.